# Use Pandas dataframe groupby.filter with own function and argument

Tags: pandas

I would like to filter my dataframe with my own filter function which require an object as argument

```
def my_filter_function(df: pd.DataFrame, my_arg: object) -> bool:
```

I know I can do the following

```
df.groupby('column_name').filter(lambda group_df: my_filter_function(group_df, my_arg))
```

But I would like to know it there is a way to simply pass my_arg as an argument in some way, which could be used by my_filter_function without using a lambda expression.

Something like this for example, but it does not work:

```
df.groupby('column_name').filter(my_filter_function, args=(my_arg,))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html?highlight=filter#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter), you can pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to the function. This is an option in python that allows a function to collect all additional arguments passed (`*args` for regular arguments, `**kwargs` for keyword arguments). Then it can pass these arguments to the received function.

The most simple way is to add a keyword argument, which will be caught by `**kwargs`, like this:

```
df.groupby('column_name').filter(my_filter_function, my_arg=my_arg)
```

You can also add a regular argument (which will be caught by `*args`), but you need to specify all other parameters beforehand. Filter only has 2 arguments - the function and dropna. If you specify `dropna` (its default is `True`) you can then add arguments that will be passed to your function:

```
df.groupby('column_name').filter(my_filter_function, True, my_arg)
```